# Moving and redrawing bitmap images leaves a "trail"? (C++)

Tags: c++, bitmap, redraw

I am trying to move and redraw an image but am getting the following problem:

http://tinypic.com/r/2m26kbm/8

Here is the code I am using to force a move, show, and then Invalidate().

```
    private: System::Void eventTimer_Tick(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
           if (!listOfBots->IsEmpty())
           {
              listOfBots->MoveBots();
              listOfBots->ShowBots();
           }
           Invalidate();
            }
```

Here is my show method:

```
void VBot::Show()
{ 
   Graphics ^ g = panel->CreateGraphics();
   g->DrawImageUnscaled( image, x, y );
   g->~Graphics();
}
```

This is all I have for my Move():

```
void SpinBot::Move()
{
   y += 2;
   x += 8;
}
```

and my constructor:

```
SpinBot::SpinBot(int atX, int atY, Panel ^ thisPanel) : VBot(atX, atY, thisPanel)
{
   energy = 500;
   image = gcnew Drawing::Bitmap("spinBotImg.bmp");
}
```

If you need any more possible code I will update this. I am not sure what is going on exactly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's not C++, is it? "^", calling constructors explicitly on stack objects, etc...

Comment: CreateGraphics() is pretty unique for being used wrong 99.9% of the time.  You are just splattering pixels to the screen.  They don't last (minimize and restore the window).  And causes artifacts here because you are not erasing the background.  Write an event handler for the panel's Paint event instead.  Call its Invalidate() method to get it to repaint after you moved the sprites.